# Plotting Polar Plots with logarithmic R-Scale using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, logarithm, polar-coordinates

I need to plot antenna radiation pattern. For this i need a logarithmic polar plot.
The Problem is, that matplotlib doesn't support the log polar plot properly.

The data for the radiation pattern is given by two numpy arrays.
One for the theta (azimuth) and one for r (gain).
The values of r correspond to the attenuation of the antenna emission in db.
This means the most outer circle of the plot corresponds to the value 0 and numbers increase towards the center.

With this code i can generate proper plots but with a linear r-scale:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
ax = plt.subplot(121, projection = 'polar')
ax.set_rlim(30,0)
ax.plot(azimuth_h, (gain_h))
ax.plot(azimuth_v, (gain_v))
ax.grid(True)
```

[Plot with linear scale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKaKc.png)

When i try to use ax.set_rscale('log') in conjunction with ax.set_rlim(30,0)
I get something like this.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
ax = plt.subplot(121, projection = 'polar')
ax.set_rscale('log')
ax.set_rlim(30,0)
ax.plot(azimuth_h, (gain_h))
ax.plot(azimuth_v, (gain_v))
ax.grid(True)
```

[Plot with log scale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsIam.png)

Is there another way of using the matplotlib for this?
Or maybe a completely different approach?

I would like to keep it as simple as possible

Thank you